# Ender 2 LCD replacement

Tags: creality-ender-3, lcd-screen

My Ender 2 LCD is suddenly not lighting up.

Is it possible to replace it with an Ender 3 LCD?

Comment: Maybe you could add an image of the Ender-2 LCD or some additional data?

Answer (score 4):

Not easily.  Some folks have been messing with both 2 and 3 LCDs and based on their posts, the [pinout is different between the two](https://amp.reddit.com/r/ender2/comments/cwxqra/pinout_for_ender2_lcd/).

Ender 2 display pinout from when one [GuzLightyear figured it out](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/issues/77) for Marlin (MKS MINI 12864 LCD):

```
          -----
     5V  | · · |  GND
   MOSI  | · · |  LCD_RS
 LCD_A0  | · · || BTN_EN2
  RESET  | · · |  BTN_EN1
BTN_ENC  | · · |  SCK
          -----
```

From a user called arnd13, the [Ender 3 equivalent](https://forum.duet3d.com/topic/7609/configuring-12864-lcd-on-maestro/7) would be:

```
         -----
5V      | · · |  GND
MOSI    | · · |  LCD_A0
SCK     | · · || BTN_EN2
CS      | · · |  BTN_EN1
BTN_ENC | · · |  Buzzer
         -----
```

Maybe you have some luck in debugging your screen (sometimes with these LCD screens, a contrast adjustment resolves the issue).